# python Copy excel file Char into word file failure.(Use Clipboard) (Word.Application)

Tags: python, win32com

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

python code Exec failure: process[word.Selection.Paste] is  Invalid.

```
from win32com import client

excel = client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")

word = client.Dispatch("Word.Application")


doc = word.Documents.Open("D:/python/My_Work/exe/word-opt/word_file.docx")

book = excel.Workbooks.Open("D:/python/My_Work/exe/word-opt/excel_file.xlsx")

char1=sheet.ChartObjects(1).Copy

doc.Bookmarks("BookMark2").Range.Select

word.Selection.Paste

doc.Save()

doc.Close()
```

the Same VBA code Exec OK:

```vb
Sub test()

Set dataExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set Workbook = dataExcel.Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\excel_file.xlsx")

Set Sheet = Workbook.Worksheets(1)

Dim WordApp As Word.Application 

Dim WordDoc As Word.Document 

Set WordApp = New Word.Application

WordApp.Visible = True

Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\word_file.docx") 

Sheet.ChartObjects(1).Copy

WordDoc.Bookmarks("BookMark2").Range.Select

WordApp.Selection.Paste

WordDoc.Save 

WordDoc.Close

WordApp.Quit 

Set WordDoc = Nothing

Set WordApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

ex: File [excel_file.xlsx] in Only a chart.